# Basic T-sql question

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have a invitation table. Like this;

```
Email           CreateDate
a@gmail.com     2011-03-04 10:10:46.273 
b@gmail.com     2011-03-10 12:06:26.673
c@gmail.com     2011-03-20 12:06:26.673
c@gmail.com     2011-03-10 12:06:26.673
```

How to return this?

```
a@gmail.com     2011-03-04 10:10:46.273    1
b@gmail.com     2011-03-10 12:06:26.673    1
c@gmail.com     2011-03-20 12:06:26.673    2
```

Comment: This can be answered by many people here on SO. What SQL have you written?

Comment: Yes is it "basic" indeed. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT Email, Max(CreateDate), Count(CreateDaate) FROM YourTable Group By Email.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Email, max(CreateDate), count(*)
from Invitation
group by Email
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following complex one also. Thus you can learn the partition by clause.

```
select a.email,max(Date),max(a.rn) from (select email,date,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by email order by email)rn from #a)a group by email
```